# How can I get sqlcipher crypto source code and does sqlcipher support data recovery mechanism?

Tags: sqlcipher

I just started looking into sqlcipher code base. I have two questions. First, I am interested in the logic/crypto part of sqlcipher source code. It looks to me that this part is implemented in C/C++ but I couldn't able to get the source code. Would you point me to code if it is available. Second, does sqlcipher support a data recovery mechanism if the user forget a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQLCipher source code is publicly available on Github [here](http://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher).  In terms of where you might start looking, I would suggest `src/crypto_impl.c`.  There is no means to extrapolate the data without having the key to the database as the entire content of the database is encrypted.